# LibreOffice Calc, make row height adjust automatically to show all cell content

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Using LibreOffice 7.4.7.2, Debian 12, KDE

The cell has the following value

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
```

But it only shows `Line1` and a bit of the next line. Can you please show how to make the cell height to expand automatically to show all the text content?

Thanks very much for any help

**ANSWER**: copied from @JohnSUN comments below

- LibreOffice calc 7.4: Menu Format, Rows, Optimal Height. Leave "Default value" option checked. Click OK. Documentation: [Optimal Row Height](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.4/en-US/text/scalc/01/05030200.html?DbPAR=CALC&HID=modules/scalc/ui/optimalrowheightdialog/dialog-action_area1#bm_id1299843)
- LibreOffice calc 7.6+: no need to do anything. The row height increases immediately after typing is completed

[image]

Comment: Does the [**Optimal Row Heights**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.4/en-US/text/scalc/01/05030200.html?DbPAR=CALC&HID=modules/scalc/ui/optimalrowheightdialog/dialog-action_area1#bm_id1299843) command work for you? Can you update Calc to a later version and check if this behavior is fixed in the new version?

Comment: @JohnSUN Format, Rows, Optimal Row height, choose default value (which is pre-selected). Does fix the issue elegantly. Can you write an answer post so I could flag it as answer for future users visiting this post? Thanks.

BTW, I cannot update LibreOffice, the package is maintained by Debian 12 stable. I use very little Office tool. As the fix you  suggested works OK. I prefer to stay with the version maintained by Debian team. Thanks.

Comment: The fact is that my comment is not an answer, not a full answer. 7.6 and later versions do not have this problem, the row height increases immediately after typing is completed. By the way, you can select the command not from the Format-Rows menu, but from the Row Number context menu - this is faster.

Comment: Right-click on the cell or row to get context menu was the first thing I tried. And there was no way to set row height. I thought the main menu format would be similar. I did try but somehow didn't see the optimal height option you mentioned. Let me edit my post to include your answer.